# Contours from Soble operator

Tags: c++, opencv

I have implemented the Sobel code from OPENCV tutorial:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html
but I am not able to implement findContours function on the "grad" Matrix (the end result from Sobel opencv).
Is it possible to use Sobel with findContours or I have to use canny (My biggest problem with Canny is that it is very slow)
Thanks very much for your help

Comment: How slow it is? In debug or release mode? What do you mean by ` I am not able to implement findContours function`, make it clearly.

Comment: The solution is at the bottom of your tutorial... `convertScaleAbs` should make your result 8 bits and make it work with findContours.... you can also use `normalize`

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that Canny return a binary image but not the Sobel method. You can only perform a findContours on a binary image as says in [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours).

> Source, an 8-bit single-channel image. Non-zero pixels are treated as 1’s.